# Classic ASP form giving SQL Server Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%%' to data type int

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

I really don't like working with classic asp but I have to...

I have this form:

```
<form name="QRForm" id="frm" method="post" action="qry.asp">  
    <input name="orderno" type="int" value="<%=Order_id%>">
    <input name="" type="submit" value="Go To Next Step" />
</form>
```

and this code in `qry.asp` to handle the Order id

```
<%Set MySQLConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
                            MySQLConn.Open "driver={SQL Server};server=..."
GetOrder = "SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE JobID='%" & Order_id &"%';"
                            Set ShowOrder = MySQLConn.execute(GetOrder)
                            if ShowOrder.EOF then%>
                            <div class="initiatives">
                                <p>No such record</p>
                            </div>
                        <%else
                            Do While Not ShowOrder.EOF%>
                            <div class="initiatives">
                                <p><span><%=ShowOrder("JobID")%></span><br />
                                <%=(ShowOrder("Payments"))%></p>
                                </div>
                        <%ShowOrder.Movenext
                            Loop
                            end if%>
```

Have I done something wrong or do I need to convert `Order_Id` to an integer? If so how? I've tried `cast` and `convert` or passing it through with a session but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the = sign which is wrong.  If you're using wildcards (%) the SQL syntax is

```
SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE JobID like '%YourValue%'.
```

I notice you're using an ODBC connection string, which should work, but Native Client or OLEDB is generally considered to be a better option for SQL Server - see the link below

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed it by using

```
<% Dim OrderId 
OrderId =Request("Order")%>

  ......

 GetOrder = "SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE JobID like'"+OrderId+"'"
```

NOTE: this way would probably leave the code vulnerable to code-injection. Its something I'm aware of -but dont care about-

I think your code should work as well John. I just wasn't able to get it to work it in my project (it returned null).
Thank you regardless though

What you mentioned about the connection string is also very interesting. This code is actually part of some amends I'm making to an older site which might it uses that.

Comment: My main point was that you need to use "like" rather than "=" in your query.  I would worry about SQL injection if it's a public facing website.  The best defence is to use range protection when you collect your form and querystring variables, you should be able to find plenty of stuff on Google about how to do this.  Querystrings are particularly vulnerable, there's a lot of ASPROX type malware out there which targets URLs containing ".asp?"